# How can I use regex in Google spreadsheet to extract and delete original text?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm using the following regular expression to extract text (of the format `G1234567`) from cell `A1` to `B1` in a Google spreadsheet:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1963, "G\d.......")
```

Extraction works fine, but I want the extracted text to be deleted from `A1` after extraction.

Here is a sample of what I currently experience when I apply the regex formula in `B1`:

```
Cell A1: ZELIA YAKUBU -G1684809  AL-MUHARAM.jpg
Cell B1: G1684809
```

How do I modify the regex to delete `G1684809` from `A1` after it's extracted into `B1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REGEXEXTRACT` doesn't *change* the text. You want `REGEXREPLACE`:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1963, "G\d+", "")
```

which *replaces* the target `Gnnnnnnn` with blank (effectively "deleting" it).